# Удаление пробелов из строки

Tags: c++, строки

Как удалить все пробелы из строки

```
string s="abc         def g ";
//
cout<<s;
```

чтобы получилось `abcdefg`?

Comment: Тот редкий случай, когда слишком простой вопрос может иметь интересное развитие... Сколькими способами нужно это сделать? :)

Comment: желательно сделать это как можно большими способами)

Comment: Большими или большим количеством? :)

Comment: большим количеством)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну, берем шаблон

```
{
    string s = "abc     def   g  ";
    // Тут должен располагаться соответствующий код
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Тогда навскидку...

1.

```
string s = "abc     def   g  ";

string v;
for(char c:s) if (c != ' ') v += c;
s = v;

cout << s << endl;
```

2.

```
string s = "abc     def   g  ";

s.erase(remove(s.begin(),s.end(),' '),s.end());

cout << s << endl;
```

3.

```
string s = "abc     def   g  ";

string v;
copy_if(s.begin(), s.end(),back_inserter(v),[](char c){ return c != ' ';});
s = v;

cout << s << endl;
```

4.

```
string s = "abc     def   g  ";

// Почти на грани фола :)

char * b = s.data();
for(char *e = b; *e; ++e)
    if (*e != ' ') *b++=*e;
*b = 0;
s = s.data();

cout << s << endl;
```

5.

```
string s = "abc     def   g  ";

s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),isspace),s.end());

cout << s << endl;
```

6.

```
string s = "abc     def   g  ";

// Только для C++20-совместимого компилятора
erase(s,' ');

cout << s << endl;
```

**Update**

Стало интересно, какой метод самый быстрый. Шестой проверить негде - VC++ 2017, так что проверял первые пять на строках в 20 миллионов символов с половиной пробелов, усреднение по 40 отдельным экспериментам. Использование перемещения при присвоении `s = move(v)` вместо `s = v` ничего не улучшило.

```
Метод     Время, мс      s = move(v)
  1       90.5 ± 2.5     89.4 ± 3.0
  2       64.4 ± 0.5
  3       86.8 ± 1.2     90.7 ± 2.8
  4       71.6 ± 1.0
  5      113.7 ± 1.4
```

Comment: Для полноты добавьте еще вариант с `remove_if(..., isspace)`.

Comment: @eanmos OK, без проблем...

Comment: Может, лучше каждый вариант сделать отдельным элементом списка? Так будет нагляднее :)

Comment: @eanmos Ну... если подправите - скажу спасибо, а меня сейчас дела призывают вдаль от компа, извините..

Comment: Извините за тупой вопрос, но где Вы берёте сведения о C++20?

Comment: @EOF Эти конкретные :) - [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2)

Comment: @eanmos, как бы вариантов очень много, так что **полноты**  по любому не будет

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, да я понимаю, просто неправильно выразился.